# SVN Checkout over HTTP fails

Tags: macos, http, svn, https, webrtc

I am trying to checkout code from webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk. When I use HTTPS, everything is fine. When I try with HTTP, I get error E175002: could not connect to repository. My subversion preferences in ~/.subversion are empty. I am using Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I installed subversion using Brew. I used Wireshark to trace the traffic and noticed that when I say svn co http://webrtc.googlecode.com/src/trunk, the traffic is on port 443 and not on port 80. Something is forcing svn to use https instead of the specified http. I also disabled VPN to make sure that is not playing any tricks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you making sure that it is read-only? Full command `svn checkout http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ webrtc-read-only` ?

Comment: I am using the instructions from [link](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started) I am stuck at gclient sync --force. This is where the svn checkout happens.

Comment: So, you using gclient sync or using svn manually?

Comment: Used gclient sync..Did not work..Then did svn manually..still did not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with Cisco AnyConnect VPN. I uninstalled it from the system and everything worked perfectly.